# dates in result column name

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day dear ones.
Please help me to query the database.

schema

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table TEST_TABLE (
    DT date,
    OBJECT_ID NUMERIC,
    PARAM_VALUE NUMERIC
);

insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-01',1, 21);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-02',1, 34);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-03',1, 78);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-04',1, 11);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-05',1, 26);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-06',1, 11);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-07',1, 12);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-08',1, 74);

insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-01',2, 18);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-02',2, 96);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-03',2, 33);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-04',2, 77);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-05',2, 55);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-06',2, 28);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-07',2, 54);
insert TEST_TABLE (DT, OBJECT_ID, PARAM_VALUE) values ('2022-01-08',2, 16);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from TEST_TABLE;
```

| DT | OBJECT_ID | PARAM_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 21 |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 | 34 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | 78 |
| 2022-01-04 | 1 | 11 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 | 26 |
| 2022-01-06 | 1 | 11 |
| 2022-01-07 | 1 | 12 |
| 2022-01-08 | 1 | 74 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 18 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 96 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2 | 33 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 | 77 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2 | 55 |
| 2022-01-06 | 2 | 28 |
| 2022-01-07 | 2 | 54 |
| 2022-01-08 | 2 | 16 |

---

**Query #2**

```
set @TARGET_DATE = '2022-01-08';

select
OBJECT_ID,
group_concat(if(DT = DATE_ADD(@TARGET_DATE, interval -1 day) , PARAM_VALUE, null)) as `dt-1`,
group_concat(if(DT = DATE_ADD(@TARGET_DATE, interval -2 day) , PARAM_VALUE, null)) as `dt-2`
from TEST_TABLE group by OBJECT_ID;
```

| OBJECT_ID | dt-1 | dt-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 11 |
| 2 | 54 | 28 |

---

I would like to receive result with dates in column names

| OBJECT_ID | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-06 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 11 |
| 2 | 54 | 28 |

Sorry about my English

Comment: *I would like to receive result with dates in column names* Study [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Akina said, prepared statement:

```
SET @TARGET_DATE = '2022-01-08';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
        'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(DT="',DT,'", PARAM_VALUE, NULL)) AS "',DT,'"')
        ORDER BY DT DESC
        SEPARATOR ', \r\n' )
        INTO @columns
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE DT >= DATE_ADD(@TARGET_DATE, interval -2 day) 
AND DT <= DATE_ADD(@TARGET_DATE, interval -1 day);

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT OBJECT_ID,',@columns,' 
                 FROM TEST_TABLE 
                 GROUP BY OBJECT_ID;') INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The final query for this will be different from your original attempt but it's based on it:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(DT="2022-01-07", PARAM_VALUE, NULL)) AS "2022-01-07", 
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(DT="2022-01-06", PARAM_VALUE, NULL)) AS "2022-01-06" 
FROM TEST_TABLE 
GROUP BY OBJECT_ID;
```

I purposely separate the creation of `@columns` and the final `@sql` query in hope that it's more easy to understand but it is possible to use a single query for the prepared statement once you've got the hang of it.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a0f00eb850d24599f9e3a1e3fb0012c)